# Efficient way to calcualate the percentage with conditions

Tags: postgresql

I have a sample data set as below:

```
TOPIC     STATUS
Physics     C
Maths       I
Chemistry   C
Chemistry   I
Chemistry   I
Maths       C
Maths       C
Physics     I
Physics     C
Maths       C
```

How do I get percent of `TOPIC` which is completed against the total attempts like below?

> Formulae for percent is 100*(Total No. of C/Total No. of Occurrence)

```
TOPIC     PERCENT
Physics     66.66
Maths       75
Chemistry   33.33
```

Usually I write sub-queries to get this if in T-SQL(I'm already familiar with). 
However, I'm new to postgreSQL and before I write the same sub-queries just wanted to check if there is an efficient way to get this in postgreSQL. 
 
**Update as requested** 
I get expected result with the below T-SQL code but looking for an efficient way using psql

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempDB..##SOO',N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##SOO
GO
SELECT * INTO ##SOO FROM(
SELECT 'PHYSICS' [TOPIC],'C' [STATUS]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PHYSICS' [TOPIC],'C' [STATUS]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PHYSICS' [TOPIC],'I' [STATUS]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MATHS' [TOPIC],'C' [STATUS]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MATHS' [TOPIC],'C' [STATUS]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MATHS' [TOPIC],'I' [STATUS]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MATHS' [TOPIC],'C' [STATUS]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CHEMISTRY' [TOPIC],'I' [STATUS]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CHEMISTRY' [TOPIC],'I' [STATUS]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CHEMISTRY' [TOPIC],'C' [STATUS]
)A

GO

SELECT S.TOPIC, 100*S.PASS/S.KNT [PERCENTO] FROM(
SELECT A.TOPIC,A.KNT,B.PASS FROM(
SELECT TOPIC, COUNT(1) [KNT] FROM ##SOO
GROUP BY TOPIC)A
JOIN 
(SELECT TOPIC, COUNT(1) [PASS] FROM ##SOO
WHERE [STATUS] ='C'
GROUP BY TOPIC)B ON A.TOPIC=B.TOPIC
)S
```

Comment: please check the update section in the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query should work just fine in Postgres if you change those identifiers to comply with standard SQL.

However it can indeed be simplified in Postgres (and SQL Server):

```
select topic, 
       (count(*) filter (where status = 'C'))::numeric / count(*) as pct
from soo
group by topic;
```

Note that the above would also work in SQL Server if you replace the `filter()` clause with a `case` expression:

```
select topic, 
       (count(case when status = 'C' then 1 end))::numeric / count(*) as pct
from soo
group by topic;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/HGTZJ63653